# Change Cursor to Pointer and Make the text bold in <td> element

Tags: javascript

I have some question regarding html. I am using AJAX to process a  element. But the problem is how do i make the text inside the td bold and change the cursor to pointer when hovering over the element. I tried onmouseover but it doesnt work.

my td element is this

```
<td id='buildingName$i' onclick='tdClick($i)'>".$row['PROJECTNAME']."</td>
```

thanks guys for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use CSS? You could easily do something like this:

```
td:hover {
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Pleasure! The simplest answers / tricks are always the best. Keeps code clean, easy to read and understand. Remember to always implement your code in the "separation of concerns" approach: HTML for markup and content, CSS for styling (and UI behaviour these days with CSS3 et al) and Javascript for interaction.

Answer (score 0):

Doing it using css is the best solution. Here is the jquery option if you need it.

```js
$("#test").hover(function(event) {
  $("#test").addClass("highlighted");
}, function(event) {
  $("#test").removeClass("highlighted");
});
```

```css
.highlighted {
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="test">HTML</td>
    <td>Javascript</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

1. use CSS as described in other answer
2. remove the onclick from the TD and instead use unobtrusive delegation - for example in jQuery:

:

```
$(function() {
  $("#tableContainer").on("click",".clickableTD",function(){
    var idx = parseInt(this.id.replace("buildingName",""),10);
    // here you do whatever you did in tdClick
  });
});
```

assuming

```
<div id="tableContainer"></div>
```

and

```
<td id='buildingName$i' class='clickableTD'>".$row['PROJECTNAME']."</td>
```